# How to get the list of checked item in itemclick of tree Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i want to get the list of checked items in itemclick in listeners from tree Panel, but the code below Ext.getCmp('treePanel').getChecked(); return nothing , because the checking process is not completed .....any one help ?

```
    var tree=Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', { 
        id:"treePanel", 
        title: 'Department', 
        width: 300,
        height: 800,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        multiSelect: true,
    //renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
       itemclick: function (thisGrid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
            if(!record.data.checked){

    var checkedItems=Ext.getCmp('treePanel').getChecked();
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: have you checked if all children inside of your store have checked property? It needs to be set to a boolean value.. Also, try using checkchange event instead of itemclick

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Ext.getCmp('treepanel')[0].getSelectionModel().selected.items;
```

**PS :** if the selectionMode is 'SINGLE' only one item will be returned

if it is 'MULTI' then multiple items will be returned